# MySQL GROUP BY ignoring ORDER BY clause

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have two queries, the only difference being the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT * FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE `hotel_city` = 'Montego Bay'
ORDER BY  `deal_score` DESC 
LIMIT 0,3;

SELECT * FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE `hotel_city` = 'Montego Bay'
GROUP BY `hotel_name`
ORDER BY  `deal_score` DESC
LIMIT 0,3;
```

The first query returns the first result with a `deal_score` of 75 but the second query returns the first result with the `deal_score` of just 72.

I would have thought that regardless of the GROUP BY clause, the first result would have the highest deal score possible (75)

The purpose of the GROUP BY clause is to optionally select a unique `hotel_name` for each result.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Normally your do not apply `GROUP BY one_or_few_columns` on queries in which you `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without being able to look at all the data, my best guess is that Group By is merging the data and giving you an arbitrary value that matches the Where clause.  This will happen if hotel name isn't unique, and you won't be given the maximum score unless you specifically query for it.

Try putting a `Max()` around deal_score.  In MySQL, Group By can be used way too easily, I like how MSSQL enforces the use of aggregate functions and grouping by every field that isn't aggregated.  Try this query:

```
SELECT `hotel_name`, MAX( `deal_score` ) AS `max_score` FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE `hotel_city` = 'Montego Bay'
GROUP BY `hotel_name`
ORDER BY  `max_score` DESC
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Comment: This answer was slightly closer to the solution as the ORDER BY `max_score` was correct.

I also needed to add all the fields individually instead of selecting *.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are facing some very `MySql` specific issue. In theory, your second query is not valid and should return an error. But `MySQL` allows for selection of so called [`hidden columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) - the columns that are not mentioned in a group by clause and not aggregated.

As stated in manual, hidden columns values are indeterminate, but in practice it usually picks up the first row walking the index used, regardless of sorting specified by `ORDER BY`, as sorting is performed **after** the grouping.

This is vendor-specific issue, so your second query should always fail if used to query other RDBMS. The correct implementation should be something like

```
SELECT max(`deal_score`) as maxdeal, `hotel_name` FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE `hotel_city` = 'Montego Bay'
GROUP BY `hotel_name`
ORDER BY maxdeal
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Comment: +1, but to be more specific, the first met record walking through the used index.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `GROUP BY` but instead `DISTINCT` since you want a *unique* `hotel_name`.

example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hotel_name -- add other fields here
FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` 
WHERE `hotel_city` = 'Montego Bay'
ORDER BY  `deal_score` DESC
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(deal_score) as maxdealscore, `hotel_name` * FROM `packages_sorted_YHZ` WHERE `hotel_city` = 'Montego Bay'
GROUP BY `hotel_name`
ORDER BY  `deal_score` DESC
LIMIT 0,3;
```